# Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 e2e failure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am facing couple of issues when running e2e_cli examples.

I was able to complete all the steps(mentioned in documentation) before running this example

**LOGS**
 sudo ./network_setup.sh up sahil
Channel name - sahil

Building configtxgen
Makefile:72: *** "No go in PATH: Check dependencies".  Stop.
Generating genesis block
2017/04/19 13:00:16 Loading configuration
2017/04/19 13:00:16 Could not find configtx.yaml in paths of [ ].Try setting ORDERER_CFG_PATH, PEER_CFG_PATH, or GOPATH correctly.
mv: cannot stat 'orderer.block': No such file or directory
Generating channel configuration transaction
2017/04/19 13:00:16 Loading configuration
2017/04/19 13:00:16 Could not find configtx.yaml in paths of [ ].Try setting ORDERER_CFG_PATH, PEER_CFG_PATH, or GOPATH correctly.
mv: cannot stat 'channel.tx': No such file or directory
Starting orderer0
peer0 is up-to-date
peer1 is up-to-date
peer2 is up-to-date
peer3 is up-to-date
Recreating cli
Channel name : sahil
2017-04-19 13:00:18.269 UTC [logging] InitFromViper -> DEBU 001 Setting default logging level to DEBUG for command 'channel'
2017-04-19 13:00:18.269 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 002 Returning existing local MSP
2017-04-19 13:00:18.269 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 003 Obtaining default signing identity
Error connecting: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: RPC failed fast due to transport failure
Error: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: RPC failed fast due to transport failure
Usage:
  peer channel create [flags]

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================== ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ==================

go is in path
 sahil.kapoor@a1dvmcphdlt01:~/work/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli $ go version
go version go1.8 linux/amd64

Could not find configtx.yaml in paths of [ ].. This file also present.

GOPATH=/home/sahil.kapoor/work
GOROOT=/usr/local/go

And my farbic folder is inside GOPATH
 /work/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli

Comment: Please format your code and logs using `code` blocks. That will be much easier to read

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there's some issue in latest e2e example which has not been fixed yet. Look at https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-3042. You should be able to run it when this gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set up a new network you will need the config files **orderer.block** and **channel.tx**

This script will create them for you.

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/e2e_cli
chmod +x generateCfgTrx.sh
./generateCfgTrx.sh <channel-ID>
```

in your case:

```
./generateCfgTrx.sh  sahil
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you have been cloning from the master branch of the git repo.

Followed these steps to get e2e_cli working( the $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric project folder):

1. Once you've cloned as per the instruction, perform

> git checkout fa3d88cde177750804c7175ae000e0923199735c

2. Download the docker images by executing the shell script

> sh examples/e2e_cli/download-dockerimages.sh

3. Remake the configtxgen file in the home folder of the project:

> make configtxgen

4. Now you can setup your network:

> sh examples/e2e_cli/network_setup.sh

Try this out and let us know if this solution fits right in!

RESULT (run docker ps):
[Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM1CZ.png)

If you still have problems, please let us know along with the logs!!!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. The solution that worked for me is to run this command before `./byfn.sh -m` generate the command is

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

This command really clears the docker containers. If you still have this issue let me know.